# Lost web permission after upgrading CentOS from 5.6 to 5.10

Tags: centos, permissions, upgrade

I upgraded CentOS from 5.6 to 5.10 using the following simple commands while logged in as root:

```
yum update

yum upgrade
```

Now, I can no longer access web pages.  All requests, regardless of type of file requested (.html, .txt, .php) yield:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /greg.dat on this
>   server. Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.website.com Port 80

PHP files will execute if called from the command line and file permissions seem fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you blindly upgraded your operating system, which is generally a bad idea, did you by any chance enable SELinux during the process? Are you able to post the output of 'getenforce'?

Comment: I did not enable SELinux. Output of 'getenforce' is: Disabled.  Thanks

Comment: @JasonIlicic Upgrades between minor versions of RHEL or CentOS (and derivatives) is typically safe and recommended. There's nothing wrong with doing this.

Comment: Perhaps @ewwhite, but now I'm paying the price for the "safe" recommendation.... ;(

Comment: @Sophie Please check your permissions... perhaps `ls -ld /var/www/html/` and also review the Apache error logs in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: error_log = `(13)Permission denied: /root/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable`

I've checked permissions.  All web files were owned by root after OS upgrade (I can't recall if that were the case before), but I've changed ownershp and permissions of a test directory and web files to 777 and a user for test purposes.  Still no permissions error from web server.

Comment: I've placed `AllowOverride None`. in httpd.conf as per [link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PcfgOpenfile), but still no love.  Also made sure every directory in webspace path had a .htaccess file.  No help.

Comment: Well, what I can conclude is that the upgrade changes the permissions of /root directory and changes some subtle aspects of how Apache deals with .htaccess and pathname roots.  Upgrade with caution!